# Is this ad at a barber shop worded correctly?

Tags: apostrophe

Recently I saw an sign at a barber shop on which I read on bold letters:

> "**Men's only**"

Is this a correct writing?

I think that it has to be "Men only" to make clear that it is a barber shop for men only.

Or am I wrong and this spelling is correct and means something I don't know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine.

"Men only" would be ambiguous. Is it a barber shop that only provides its services to men? Or are women and children not allowed in the shop? What if a man comes in with his little daughter? Will the little girl not be allowed to enter the shop?

"Men's only" works fine because it means "Men's [haircut] only". So, yes, your wife and child can accompany you, but they can't get a haircut in that shop.

Comment: Well, they could probably get what some would call a men's cut.